# COMO PASAR UNA URL O HTML COMO PARAMETRO A LA LIBRERIA HTML2PDF.JS

Tags: javascript, html, html2pdf

estoy intentando crear un boton que me convierta una pagina html en pdf con la libreria html2pdf y quisiera en ves de pasar un elemento seleccionado con querryselector o con getElemntById pasar una url porque la pagina que quiero pasar a pdf no es la misma donde esta el boton y por lo tanto no me toma el selector.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const $boton = document.querySelector("#btnCrearPdf");
$boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const $elementoParaConvertir = document.body;
    html2pdf()
        .set({
            margin: 1,
            filename: 'Contrato.pdf',
            image: {
                type: '',
                quality: 0.98
            },
            html2canvas: {
                scale: 3,
                letterRendering: true,
            },
            jsPDF: {
                unit: "in",
                format: "a4",
                orientation: 'portrait'
            }
        })
        .from($elementoParaConvertir)
        .save()
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
});
```

que podría hacer?

Comment: la pagina que intentas mandar a pdf, es un template?

Comment: @ChristianGtz si, osea tengo 3 documentos 1 donde esta el boton, 2 el archivo javascript, 3 el archivo que quiero pasar a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

modifica la variable `$elementoParaConveritir`
El código lo que hace es asignarle a esta variable todo el `body` del documento actual y es lo que se convertirá a pdf.

```js
$boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //Aquí le asignas la estructura html que quieres convertir a pdf
    //
    const $elementoParaConvertir = document.body;
    html2pdf()
        .set({
            margin: 1,
            filename: 'Contrato.pdf',
            image: {
                type: '',
                quality: 0.98
            },
            html2canvas: {
                scale: 3,
                letterRendering: true,
            },
            jsPDF: {
                unit: "in",
                format: "a4",
                orientation: 'portrait'
            }
        })
        .from($elementoParaConvertir)
        .save()
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Una forma que se me ocurre es la siguiente

```js
$boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "laRutaAl/archivo.html", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    const $elementoParaConvertir = xmlhttp.responseText;
    html2pdf()
        .set({
            margin: 1,
            filename: 'Contrato.pdf',
            image: {
                type: '',
                quality: 0.98
            },
            html2canvas: {
                scale: 3,
                letterRendering: true,
            },
            jsPDF: {
                unit: "in",
                format: "a4",
                orientation: 'portrait'
            }
        })
        .from($elementoParaConvertir)
        .save()
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

La idea de como leer el archivo html la obtuve de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930681/12812277) respuesta de stackoverflow en ingles

Comment: Hola, lo intente y no me dío resultado, tambien lo habia intentado antes haciendo la peticion con axios el resultado es un pdf pero con muchas paginas en blanco, y tambien intente de esta manera const $elementoParaConvertir = document.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; y me da el mismo resultado.